# How to custom components folder path in laravel?

Tags: laravel

My view folders is like

```
views/
└── web/
    ├── Frontend
    │   ├── layout
    │   ├── admin
    │   ├── profile
    │   
    └── Backend
        ├── layout
        ├── user
        ├── post
```

I need to make it like this:

```
views/
└── web/
    ├── Frontend
    │   ├── layout
    │   ├── admin
    │   ├── components
    │   
    └── Backend
        ├── layout
        ├── user
        ├── components
```

each section has his own`components`

Is there any way to achieve to this point ?

Comment: Your question is really unclear. Clarify more

Comment: @TalhaF.  simply put components folder inside Frontend folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you would do for views, you can use the dot notation to specify the path, and so if you have a component called `item.blade.php` inside `views/web/Frontend/components` you can use

```
@component('web.Frontend.components.item', [...])
   ...
@endcomponent
```

Then in order to bind variables from the view to the component, you just need to pass them in the array.
Example, in your view you have a `$var1` which in the component has `$var2` as name, you just need to pass it like this:

```
@component('web.Frontend.components.item', ['var1'=>$var2])
   ...
@endcomponent
```

Comment: That's cool man! but how can I bind the var in @component blade?

Comment: @AbdulHakeem a year later ahahah